# How to Publish web Site without publishing profile

Tags: asp.net, batch-file, batch-processing, web-deployment

I am trying to Publish an asp.net website with four parameters (Service URL, Site/application, Username, Password) from the command line. 
Is there a way to publish without using publishing profile?

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild Mywebsit.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot, for reference you can see [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/command-line-deployment)